# How to access Mysql::Result in ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Example:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select 'ABC'")
```

How can I get the `'ABC'` value from `result`? Tried `result.first` without success. Thanks

p.s. Gems:

> activerecord (2.3.9)
>   mysql (2.8.1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could try it on the cosole:

```
script/console # rails 2
rails console  # rails 3
```

enter your code in the console and you get:

```
irb> result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select 'ABC'")
 => [{0=>"ABC", "'ABC'"=>"ABC"}]
```

so it you get it with

```
result.first[0]
# or
result.first['ABC']
```

`result.first` just returns the first row, not the first value. This row consists of a Hash with numerical and named access.

Comment: Thanks jigfox. For the result `[{0=>"ABC", "'ABC'"=>"ABC"}]`, why there is 2 "ABC"s? and, what is the meaning of `0` and first `"'ABC'"`? Is one of them a column name? As when I do the query in MySQL Query Browser, the column name is `ABC` and the value is first row is `ABC`.

Comment: result is `#<Mysql::Result:0x102f5e0d0>` instead of `[{0=>"ABC", "'ABC'"=>"ABC"}]`. What gives?

Comment: *"why there is 2 "ABC"s? and, what is the meaning of 0 and first "'ABC'"?"* One is accessible by the Column number "1" and one is accessible by the column name "ABC".

Comment: as to your mysql result: it shouldn't matter, you should still be able to access you values like in a array of hashs.

Comment: @ohho - Ran into the same issue/question.  We are using an old version of Ruby/Rails and MySQL. In the script/console changed it to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_one("select 'ABC'")` and got back something sensible...

Answer (score 26):

Instead of `.execute` you could use `.select_all`, this will return an array with the result.

So use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select 'ABC'")
```

Comment: This returns an ActiveRecord::Result.

Answer (score 23):

Try:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value("select 'ABC'")
```

I wouldn't advise messing around with the underlying database code if you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks Shadwell. I give the answer credit to jigfox as I am looking for the general return structure from a MySQL query, not limited to a value. A `useful` credit for you ;-)

Comment: with 500k+ records you really can't do select all because of the speed.   This is also usually the reason people tend to use connection.execute so they can optimize the SQL being processed.